# include_root_in_json from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I'm trying to return a result to a view where the json does not include the root.

I don't want to set this on all actions for this model,so therefore am trying to avoid setting

```
ActiveRecord.Base.include_root_in_json = false
```

I was hoping that I could do

```
@task = Tasks.all
@task.include_root_in_json = false
```

To get the response I need, but that doesn't seem to be working, returning an 'undefined method include_root_in_json= for #

Is there a nice way of doing this??

Answer (score 12):

It's an old question now, but the answers were not updated, and **Rails 3.2 filled the gap** ([Rails source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/3-2-stable/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb))

**With Rails 3.2, you can now use:**

```
my_model.to_json(:root => false)
```

if you don't want the root key to be included.

It gets even better as I just tested it with an array, so you can do:

```
Model.all.to_json(:root => true)
```

Comment: This is obviously the correct answer! not the one with 5 votes :)

Answer (score 5):

From looking at the source for [ActiveModel::Serializers::JSON#as_json](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activemodel/lib/active_model/serializers/json.rb), it appears there is not a way to change the value of `include_root_in_json` on a per-method-call basis. Unless I'm missing something, your best recourse is to change the class variable before your call and change it back afterward:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = false
render :json => @task
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json = true
```

This is pretty ugly, but it seems that the "include root in json" option wasn't designed with this level of flexibility in mind. It might also cause a race condition with other requests, but I'm not sure about that. Alternatively, you could always keep it set to false, and manually create a hash with a root key in cases where you need that:

```
# this case
render :json => @task

# some other case
render :json => { :my_model => @my_model.to_json }
```

Comment: thanks Jimmy. can you explain what you mean by 'change class variable before you call and change it back after'?? I'm not sure I get it.

Comment: Who in his insane mind thought of this?!?! Why not just add an option to the to_json with this setting? I sometimes don't get rails...

Comment: Ridiculous indeed. This prevents interoperability of any code that uses to_json. Baffling.