# Rails render :json => [1,2,3] behaving differently in production (json root)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, bundler

I'm seeing some weird behaviour in my Rails app. I'm running ruby 1.9.2-p290, and I have this sort of controller:

```
class NumbersController < ApplicationController

  def index
    render :json => [1,2,3]
  end

end
```

Imagine I run the servers like this to demonstrate the problem:

```
$ rails s # This one runs in "development" on port 3000
$ RAILS_ENV=production rails s -p 2999 # This one runs in "production" on port 2999
```

In development or test mode, my result would be

```
$ curl localhost:3000/numbers # development
{numbers: [1,2,3]} # The root is being included in the json, as inferred from the controller name.
$ curl localhost:2999/numbers # production
[1,2,3] # No root in the JSON
```

I've been over the app with a fine tooth comb and there are no obvious configuration differences that look like they would affect json between development and production. Also, no lines like "if Rails.env === 'production'"

I'm guessing that different gems are being required, e.g. for assets, which are changing the behaviour of render :json => ... . I've inspected the versions of the "json" and "multi_json" gems from within the running apps, and they are the same (1.7.5 and 1.3.6 respectively, and multi_json uses the same adapter.). How do I find out exactly which gems are required from *within* the app while it is running? Also, does anyone have any alternative explanations?

EDIT: I'm running Rails 3.1.1 and the assets part of my Gemfile is:

```
group :assets do
  gem "ember-rails"
  gem "jquery-rails"
  gem "less", "2.0.7"
  gem "less-rails", "2.0.2"
  gem 'uglifier'
end
```

Comment: The "root" in the JSON isn't being produced as a result of ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json.

Turns out that whatever the action name, the result (in development) is always "{#{controller_name.pluralize}: #{array_i_passed_in}}" if I pass in an array, or just "#{the_object_i_passed_in}"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a workaround here: [include_root_in_json from controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097477/include-root-in-json-from-controller)

The solution:

```
render :json => {:numbers => [1,2,3]}, :root => false # If you want the root
```

:root => true isn't being respected in production. I suspect the as_json or to_json has been overridden incorrectly in that environment.

I'm still not happy though, because I can't rely on render :json => [1, 2, 3].

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is controlled by this setting in config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb for new rails apps.

```
# Disable root element in JSON by default.
ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
  self.include_root_in_json = false
end
```

It could be that because your controller doesn't reference any AR (ActiveRecord) classes, AR isn't yet loaded due to lazy loading in development mode. Hence the setting is true.

You could test that theory by putting `ActiveRecord::Base` in your index action to force it to load.

Comment: You mean just by doing
def index
  ActiveRecord::Base

Comment: And then the render call, yes. See if having ActiveRecord loaded changes the json serialiser's behavior. I know you're not using an AR object but it could work..

Comment: Tried it, and including your config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb, but it didn't work. To prove that ActiveRecord::Base isn't at fault I tried replacing it literally with [1,2,3], and I still get the same results.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be looking for the following configuration:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.include_root_in_json
```

It produces exactly the difference you are getting between the JSON representations of object: if set to true the Object name is added as a root key of the produced JSON.

Comment: I've actually got that set to false for that particular model, and I think I'm passing an array rather than an instance of ActiveRecord::Relation.

Comment: I literally tried replacing the data with [1,2,3] and got the same weird behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I find out exactly which gems are required from within the app
>   while it is running?

The `Gemfile.lock` file specifies this.

Comment: Not quite - in the original question I actually meant "Which gems are `require`d at runtime", in the context of when there are several different JSON gems in the Gemfile. I don't do RoR any more, but in hindsight I would somewhat desperately monkey patch `require` or monkey patch rubygems's require monkey patch to log each gem as it gets required.

Comment: @user1158559 thanks for the clarification. Out of curiosity: Why don't you do RoR any more?

Comment: Thanks - wanted to do data science instead. Companies would offer jobs that required part web dev and part data science, but they would greatly exaggerate the data science part. The only solution was to refuse to do any kind of web development work!

Comment: There are a few technical reasons as well

Comment: @user1158559 Interesting. By 'greatly exaggerate the data science part', do you mean that they would expand (feature creep) the work related to that, once started? Or that they would put emphasis on recruiting people with that skillset exclusively?

Comment: @user1158559 What technical reasons would you highlight as the most important, in summary?

Comment: the companies and recruiters would exaggerate it during interviews to get me interested (I mainly work for startups)....

Comment: Tech-wise:
  - Slowness, especially when loading applications (although I know it vastly improved with Ruby 2)
  - Fragility of applications and gems
  - In general, too much emphasis on style, i.e. RSpec vs Test::Unit vs Cucumber e.t.c.
  - Popularity - which reduced the quality of Q&A on stack overflow

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155089/discussion-between-magne-and-user1158559).