# Backbone.js nested model with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

So I am getting this annoying nested object problem. I generate JSON data from a rails model and pass it into a backbone model like this:

```
board = Board.find(anyid)
covers = [link1, link2]

return_json = {
 board: user,
 covers: covers
}

resond_to do |format|
 format.js { render json: return_json }
end
```

And in my backbone end, I get something like this:

[image]

Why is the board object nested with another object? I've ran into this situation several times, and I have to do something like `@model.get("board").board.name` to retrieve the value. This is annoying. However you can see that the array works as I expected.

If I didn't make it clear, please comment! I will be around.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097477/include-root-in-json-from-controller

Comment: @rjz Thank you sir! Exactly what I want.

Comment: You bet. Glad it helped!