# Rails: When I render json in controller I get controller name in answer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I get an action in my controller:

```
def autocomplete_client
    clients = Client.filter(params[:q], params[:field_name])
    answer = clients.map{|cl| cl.attributes.merge(value: cl.send(params[:field_name]))}
    render json: answer
end
```

It's work fine. But in browser I get my 'answer' nested to object with one field - name of controller.

```
{"agency_orders":[{"id":2,"fio":"sasd","passport":"","birthday":null,"phone":"","email":null,"comment":null,"created_at":"2016-01-04T11:58:09.736Z","updated_at":"2016-01-04T11:58:09.736Z","value":"sasd"}]}
```

When 'agenyc_orders' is name of controller.
I want get only array with data.

How can I get this behavior?

Comment: I just found out an answer here, does it help for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5097477/include-root-in-json-from-controller

Comment: You can use jbuilder. https://github.com/rails/jbuilder